# How do you calculate and angle using Math.asin()?

Tags: javascript, function, math

I'm trying to create a triangle calculator to practice my JavaScript Math functions and i hit a roadblock. Using `Math.asin(opp/hyp)` gives me a number between 0-1, so how would i calculate B with the opposite and hypotenuse?

```
if(((opp!=""||opp!=0)&&(hyp!=""||hyp!="0"))&&((A=="0"||A=="")&&(B=="0"||B==""))){
    var sin = Math.asin(opp/hyp)
    document.getElementById("B").value=(sin)
}
```

I would be grateful for alternative solutions and fixes to my issue as i'm not very experienced in the area

Comment: That's not true: `Math.asin()` returns the angle which falls in the range of `[0rad, (Math.PI / 2)rad]` (aka 0deg to 180deg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.asin gives you an angle in radians.

1rad × 180/π = 57.296° (just multiply by 180 and divide by Math.PI)

Comment: Thanks so much, i have never understood the functions and there arent many guide on how to do it

Comment: @OakleySchofield If this answer helped you please mark it as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it.